# Difference in quotas of free and GSuite Enterprise Google products

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I try to find differences in quotas of Google Spreadsheets and App Scripts, used by free account vs. GSuite Enterprise account.

The only document i've got is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas. But there i miss such quotas as `ImportXml`.

Comment: I believe that they have removed the quota

Comment: What make you think that there is a quota for IMPORTXML?

Answer (score 2):

Besides looking in https://developers.google.com/apps-script also look at

- https://support.google.com/docs Goodle Docs Editors Help Center
- https://support.google.com/a G Suite Help Center for G Suite Administrator
- https://developers.google.com/sheets "Micro-site" about Google Sheets for developers

You might also should subscribe/follow to the G Suite Update Blog where changes to G Suite (including Google Sheets) are usually announced.